# How to get DOM data from website

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-scraping

I like to scrap all data from [this site](http://www.racingpost.com/horses/seasonal_stats_home.sd#seasonStatsTabs=jockey_seasonal_stats) . Unfortunately there is a DOM. I open the site by webbrowser. I tried to click page 2 on the site and then read websource but it didnt help.

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
doc.All["seasonalStatsTrainersPagerlink1_2"].InvokeMember("Click");
```

I still see websource of page1. Is there anyway to get websource of page 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the Jockey data in the grid, here is the URL:
http://www.racingpost.com/horses/jockey_seasonal_stats.sd?ssn_type=GB+Jumps&ssn_id=355&sort=WINS&sortOrder=DESC&page=2

You can change the page number at the end to get different pages (you can also change the column to sort and the order)

Comment: How did you know what to write in URL?

Answer (score 1):

Link looks like http://www.racingpost.com/horses/jockey_home.sd?jockey_id=13499#topJockTabs=jockey_race_record&bottomJockTabs=jockey_form

Try playing with jockey_id

Comment: How did you know what to write in URL?